# Open Source Triple store for OWL

Tags: owl, triplestore, rdfstore

I'm new with triple stores and I need a good recommendation for an open source triple store, where I can store OWL files. Does someone have some recommendations for me? Thank you a lot! Bests M

Answer (score 4):

I think 4Store would be a good choice, which is fast and stable. 
You can get some information from [project repository](https://github.com/garlik/4store)

[Jena TDB](http://jena.apache.org/documentation/tdb/index.html) and <del>Sesame</del> [RDF4J](http://rdf4j.org/about/) would be another choice. Both are open source. You can refer the comparison between Jena and Sesame [here](https://web.archive.org/web/20160524201836/http://answers.semanticweb.com:80/questions/1638/jena-vs-sesame-is-there-a-serious-complete-up-to-date-unbiased-well-informed-side-by-side-comparison-between-the-two)

Other materials:
More [large triple stores introduction](http://www.w3.org/wiki/LargeTripleStores).
[RDF Store Benchmarking](http://www.w3.org/wiki/RdfStoreBenchmarking)

Answer (score 3):

As OWL files are RDF, any RDF triplestore will do for storing them - though not every triple store will support OWL reasoning (but then again, you might not even need that).

Some popular open source choices for RDF storage/querying are OpenRDF Sesame, Apache Jena, OpenLink Virtuoso, Redland, 4store, and dotNetRdf. It's probably worth pointing out that several of these (e.g. Sesame, Jena, dotNetRdf) are storage-neutral APIs, which means that several other (open source & commercial) triplestores can be accessed via them.

So which triplestore/API you pick depends on your requirements in terms of things like ease of use, scalability, reasoning support required, and just generally which one you think looks cool. Have a look at [this page](https://web.archive.org/web/20150728043541/http://answers.semanticweb.com:80/questions/397/what-are-specific-triplestore-strengths-and-weaknesses) for an overview of some of the strengths and weaknesses of the various offerings.

Comment: I'd also add that you have the option of using a dedicated OWL reasoner (such as Pellet or HermiT).  These won't provide persistent storage, and won't scale to the same level a database will, but they'll probably give you the best performance for reasoning and are your only options if you need DL reasoning.  There is also a pretty good list of triple stores here: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Triplestore