# Java ME Triple Store

Tags: java-me, ontology, cdc, triplestore

I'm currently coding a Java ME program that has an internal OWL reasoning engine (Hermit & Pellet) and receives ontology data (sensor data) from a backend server. Sometimes this data is also composed of raw sensor data and already reasoned results from a reasoner on the backend server. The reasoning will only be performed on the mobile device in case of network failures.

At this moment I'm lacking a good method of storing the backend data for further processing.
I've already looked up Triple Stores, but I was wondering if there are any good ones for Java ME applications?

Grtz

Neo

Comment: FYI for future readers: (5 april 2015) I wanted to let you know the project resulted as "not possible on mobile devices due to the current limitations of the hardware".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're approaching this the wrong way.  Do the reasoning on the server and send the results to your application.

Reasoning is computationally difficult.  Trying to do it on a mobile device will either be a terrible user experience because it's slow, or just won't work on anything but toy data.

There are RDF databases that perform reasoning which are quite good, and if you *really* need DL reasoning, there are a number of dedicated OWL reasoners which it would not be hard to put a SPARQL endpoint in front of so you can query them remotely.  Pick one that best suits your needs and go with it; do the reasoning in the backend, get the results via SPARQL protocol (HTTP).

Comment: Thank you for your comment, but this is a research project on mobile reasoning for help in emergency cases (with local reasoning on the mobile device, in case of network failures). I cannot change the specifications that were made for this project. At this moment the reasoning is actually performing quite fast (from 1 to 3 seconds) on mobile devices. The only problem I'm actually encountering is storing loads of data in an unefficient way in the memory. That's why I asked if anybody knew a more efficient way like  triple stores?

Comment: If you are finding the memory utilization to be an issue, you can try and use something that uses query time reasoning, rather than something that will compute classification & realization up front.  But that will mean queries will be slower and use more memory to evaluate.  There's no magic bullet here.

Comment: Again thank you for your comment and the rich information, but the point of the research is actually discovering how fast/good mobile devices are in using reasoning engines and rule engines together.

I found another question from a user which you answered: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13155676/open-source-triple-store-for-owl?rq=1

Perhaps I should have included this information in the question, but I'm currently using Hermit for reasoning and will compare it with Pellet. The only problem I had was the need for persistent storage of sensor data on the mobile device.

Comment: I wanted to let you know the project resulted as "not possible on mobile devices due to the current limitations of the hardware". Thus your answer was the best "current" solution.